# Is there any way that I can get a full BeautifulSoup element?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I've been trying to build this little script that downloads every from a website but I've ran into a problem.When I search the BeautifulSoup element I can't get all the div tags from that element.

Here is my code:

```
#! python3

from selenium import webdriver
import bs4
import requests
import time
import os
import re

url = "https://www.flickr.com/"

#os.makedirs("downloaded_photos", exist_ok=True)

while True:
    search_input = input("Please insert here what kind of photos would you like to donwload: ")

    if search_input == "":
        print("")
        print("Please don't leave this space blank!")
        print("")
        time.sleep(1)
        continue

    else:
        print("Searching...")

        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get(url + "search/?text=" + search_input)

        res = requests.get(url + "search/?text=" + search_input)
        res.raise_for_status()

        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
        all_the_imgs = soup.find(
            "div", class_="main search-photos-results")
    
        result = re.findall(r'\.jpg', str(all_the_imgs))

        print(len(result))

        driver.close()


        break
```

So my question is if there is any way that I can get all the div tags from the selected element

Comment: `soup.findAll("div", ...)` ?

Comment: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you simply need to use `find_all` on your `search-photo-results` element

```
all_the_imgs = soup.find_all(
    "div",
    class_="main search-photos-results",
)
```

we could append this list returned back by our `regex` into a dictionary called `map`, using selenium's `current_url` output as a key for later inspection.

```
map = {}


all_images = re.findall(r'\.jpg', str(all_the_images))
map[driver.current_url] = all_images
```